# Powershell and Azure SQL Database Sync

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

We are using the SQL Database Sync feature in Azure and whilst it generally works without issues it does occasionally fail. The failures can be due to lost database connections or failures in which the error messages in the Azure Sync Log don't help. I see no way in the Azure portal to set up alerts to email us when a sync fails and I don't see any Azure cmdlets that will return the status of a database sync. Does anyone have any ideas how we can add monitoring to the service?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did crosspost this later to the msdn forum that user6133663 listed below.

The answer from Xu Ye (who I assume works for MS) was:

*You are right. Currently SQL Data Sync did not support API & failure alert. We will keep you update if any update on this.*

So, to answer my original question, there is currently no way to monitor the success or failure of a SQL database sync.